# Entity Framework & Reverse Engineer Code First & MySQL: error access denied

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework Reverse Engineer Code First with MySQL DB, I have installed these: mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.3 & mysql-connector-net-6.9.3

The connection to MySQL DB seems to work:
[image]

I get the following error:

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return
>   a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication to host
>   'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password'
>   failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I tried a lot of solutions found on the internet but nothing works.

Here is the connection string I have in the web.config:

```
   <add name="TFEContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;
  port=3306;database=tfe_schema;uid=root;password=********"/>
```

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` even though both your test screen and your connection string you listed are showing a password... Seems to me that it's not using the connection string you think it is.

Comment: @Andrew Counts, You're right and the connection string is normally generated by EF automatically, I shouldn't add it to the web.config manually as I did for testing.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of search, I checked the box "Save my password" and it's working but the password to access the MySQL server is hardcoded in the web.config. [image]